# Does PhoneStateListener work in Phonegap Plugin?

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, phone-state-listener

I am trying to get the cdma signal strength using PhoneStateListener in a phonegap plugin for android. Does PhoneStateListener work in Phonegap plugin? or Please let me know whats wrong with my code.

```
public void getNetworkSignalStrength()
    {   
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TelephonyManager phonyManager  = (TelephonyManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                PhoneStateListener mListener = new PhoneStateListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
                        Log.d("PhoneStateListener", "I am here");
                        int strengthAmplitude = signalStrength.getCdmaDbm();
                        cdmaStrength = String.valueOf(strengthAmplitude);
                        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
                    }
                };
                phonyManager.listen(mListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTH);  

            }

        };
        this.ctx.runOnUiThread(runnable);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTH is deprecated . Please try using PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS..